# Ventilating utility room with gas appliances

Tags: safety, gas, ventilation

I have a 20 sq ft utility room hosting a water heater and hydronic boiler, both gas. The door to the room is louvered, to allow for air passage. In addition to that, I was wondering if installing air registers on top of the room near the ceiling, which I could easily do without much (aesthetic) cost, would provide additional safety and prevent combustion-related incidents (fire, carbon monoxide etc). Would they lower the risk of something like carbon monoxide?

Comment: "Would they lower the risk of something like carbon monoxide?" In what way are you thinking? CO is an output of the burning of gas (of any sort). If the burners are properly vented, there should be no risk of CO. If the door to the utility room is vented, the burners should be getting plenty of air to burn. I'm a bit lost on what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If the gas heaters are getting enough combustion air, then more won't help.  Won't hurt either.  For fire, carbon monoxide, need inspection and tune up/maintenance done by license people.

Comment: The water heater and boiler should/better be vented separately to the outside. The louvered door is more than likely for intake air, not venting the utility room.

Comment: Hey all -- I don't mean vented through the chimney, of course that is there, I mean air registers to improve air circulation INSIDE THE UTILITY ROOM

Comment: "of course that is there" ....  Didn't mean to offend but you'd be surprised at what we see here.